# MySQLi query retorna null

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

estoy tratando de hacer una consulta para ver si existe un registro, y en caso de que exista, me retorne el ID, pero en lugar de ID o False me está retornando null y esto no entra en la condición que estoy colocando en la respuesta.

Este es el código AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'buscar-factura.php?fact='+txtFactura
        })
        .done(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            if(!response){
                console.log('No hay registro');
            } else {
                console.log('Sí hay registro');
            }
       })
```

Para el PHP estoy usando dos archivos, el archivo de conexión y el archivo en el que mando a llamar la función.

Archivo "buscar-factura.php"

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    require_once 'conn.php';
    $objDB = new DataBase;
    $fact = $_GET['fact'];
    $result = $objDB->BuscarFactura($fact);
    $arr = $result->fetch_assoc();
    die(json_encode($arr));
?>
```

Archivo "conn.php"

```
class DataBase{
    private $srvr = '192.168.0.7';
    private $user = 'cmarrufo';
    private $pass = 'B@53%de%D4t05';
    private $db = 'aduana';
    // private $srvr = 'localhost';
    // private $user = 'root';
    // private $pass = 'Pass290414';
    // private $db = 'aduana';
    function Conexion(){
        $mysqli = new mysqli($this->srvr, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);
        $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
        if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
            die('Error de Conexión (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
                    . $mysqli->connect_error);
        }else{
            return $mysqli;
            $mysqli->mysqli_close();
        }
    }
function BuscarFactura($fact){
        $conexion = $this->Conexion();
        return $conexion->query("SELECT IdFactura FROM FACTURA WHERE Factura = '".$fact."'");
    }
}
```

Comment: El `die()` ? Déjalo tal cual `json_encode`

Comment: esos son datos reales de una db??? :facepalm:

Comment: mira esto por favor: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php/53280?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C0.0000#53280

Comment: Y de paso, viene algo en fact? el parametro esta bien?

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, no entendí tu pregunta de si eran datos reales de una base de datos, pero ajá.

En fact sí, va el número de factura, ingresando un número existente o no, me da igual, null.

Comment: si son datos de una base de datos real, los expusiste a internet, y ahora los tiene cualquiera. Tenes que avisar, que cambien todos los datos. si la conexion es correcta, y viene algo en numero de factura, entonces alguien mas va a poder ayudarte... igual vuelvo a preguntar.. una cosa es que me digas que viene algo, y otra que estes seguro que llega algo... ru variable $fact tiene el numero de factura?

Comment: Sí, $fact recibe el número de la factura, ya lo comprobé anteriormente.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código tiene dos problemas:

1. Programación *optimista*. Parece contradictorio, pero es un error programar de modo *optimista*, o sea, ignorando los posibles errores, creyendo que vivimos en un mundo color de rosas. Una parte fundamental de la programación es prever los errores, **todos los errores posibles** y afrontarlos.
2. Programación con poco rigor, o incoherente. Me explico: en el cliente tú evalúas de este modo: `if(!response){ console.log('No hay registro'); } else { console.log('Sí hay registro'); }` pero en tu código las salidas campan a sus anchas con cosas como esta: `die('Error de Conexión ....)` en el caso de error de conexión, el código del cliente asumirá que hay registros, porque evalúas una respuesta vacía, pero hay respuesta de error ... o peor aún, si el cliente espera un json, lo estarás rompiendo con el `die` en ese manejo de error. Lo que se suele hacer en estos casos es controlar el código, poniendo un array con una clave error por ejemplo, ligado a un mensaje.

Veamos:

La clase `DataBase` debería ser modificada de este modo. Hay mucho código inservible ahí y malas prácticas, pero dejemos eso por ahora.

#### `conn.php`

```
class DataBase{
    private $srvr = '192.168.0.7';
    private $user = 'cmarrufo';
    private $pass = 'B@53%de%D4t05';
    private $db = 'aduana';
    // private $srvr = 'localhost';
    // private $user = 'root';
    // private $pass = 'Pass290414';
    // private $db = 'aduana';
    function Conexion(){
        $mysqli = new mysqli($this->srvr, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);
        $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
        return $mysqli;
    }

function BuscarFactura($fact){
        return $this->Conexion->query("SELECT IdFactura FROM FACTURA WHERE Factura = '".$fact."'");
    }
}
```

---

#### `buscar-factura.php`

```
<?php
    require_once 'conn.php';
    $objDB = new DataBase;
    $mData=array();
    if($objDB) {
        $fact = $_GET['fact'] ?? null;
        if($fact) {
            $result = $objDB->BuscarFactura($fact);
            if ($arr = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
                $mData['datos']=$arr;
            } else {
                $mData['error']='No se encontraron filas';
            }
        } else {
            $mData['error'] = 'No se postearon datos';
        }
    } else {
        $mData['error'] = 'No hay conexión';
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    die(json_encode($mData));
?>
```

Finalmente, en el cliente:

```
$.ajax({
            method: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'buscar-factura.php?fact='+txtFactura
        })
        .done(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            if(response.error){
                console.log(response.error);
            } else {
                console.log('Sí hay registro');
                console.log(response.datos);
            }
       })
```